# Java multi literal print?

Tags: java

Okay so I'm brand new to programming and I am trying to figure out how to print out one of every literal on a single line or multiple lines if possible with a single `System.out.println` statement.

I've tried the following.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print ("Hello")(123.45f)(3591)('#')(3487.3847)(1>9)(0B0101110)(0x271);
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print ("Hello");(123.45f);(3591);('#');(3487.3847);(1>9);(0B0101110);(0x271);
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print ("Hello" \n123.45f \n3591 \n'#' \n3487.3847 \n1>9 \n0B0101110 \n0x271);
    }
}
```

Comment: `print` expects, among other things, a `String` argument. What are you trying to pass as an argument?

Comment: What's wrong with several printlns?

Comment: `print` only prints one thing at a time (doesn't have to be a String, can be other things, but just one)

Comment: trying to pass as an argument? I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: I suppose nothing is wrong with several print lines except that I don't want to do that. I understand that I can print everything on multiple lines. I am trying to understand how I would print all of that out on the same line.

Comment: You should start by reading JAVA's documentation, then do a few tutorials. Because this is a more than a *very* basic question you are asking here.

Comment: I guess im asking how I would do something like this

class Test4 {
public static void main (String[] args){                                                      System.out.print ("Number\n0b00110011");
}
} 
and have it show up as 
"number
51"
on two lines? mixing a string and a binary on one line or any of the others listed.

Answer (score 1):

your code does not even compile and they are not even syntactically correct for Java.  And, no, there is on way to print using one `println` as you want to.

There are some ways you can take, for example

1. Use multiple println, which is most straight-forward
2. Use printf:

   ```
   System.out.printf("%s\n%d\n%s\n", "hello", 12.3, "world");
   ```
3. Make up a little helper yourself

   ```
   public static void printlns(Object ... args) {
       for (Object.a : args) {
           String.out.println(String.valueof(a));
       }
   }
   ```

   so you can do something like

   ```
   printlns("test", 123.45, true);
   ```

Comment: I appreciate the help. I was just trying to find a shorter way than multiple println or what you've listed. I got the two to mix by doing

class Test {
public static void main (String[] args){

    int n = 0b00110011;
    
    System.out.println ("Number" + n);
}
}
so it comes out number51.

I can use the \n command if its a string ("hello\nworld"). 
I know my syntax was wrong I just assumed that since i'm totally new there was just something I didn't know instead of it not being possible. Much appreciated for all the quick responses.

Comment: Make up a little helper util method should be something achievable.  If you don't even like that, then the answer is a simple "No, you cannot do it in Java"